# Not able to implement doPost() method

Tags: java, servlets

I am learning Java Servlets. Trying to implement the doPost() method, however I get an error that "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL".

Code

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<form name="Form1" action="http://localhost:8080/examples/servlet/ColorGetServlet" method="post">
<B>Color:</B>
<select name="color" size="1">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ColorGetServlet extends HttpServlet{

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException{

    String color = request.getParameter("color");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    pw.println("<B>The Selected Color is: ");
    pw.println(color);
    pw.close();
    } 
}
```

Will appreciate if anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It is a best-practice to use `@Override` when overriding a method, just to make the compiler helps you to ensure that you did it right.

Comment: You need to check your servlet mapping in web.xml - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577414/http-status-405-http-method-post-is-not-supported-by-this-url

Comment: servlet mapping is correct. If i user doGet() instead of goPost() it works.

Comment: is there a chance that you have an old class somewhere? Can you post the web.xml configuration?

Comment: Did you happen to test this servlet using doGet() method and then changed it to doPost()? I mean, if that's the case, then may be it's still referring to the old class file. Just the possibility ... !

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar may be right, please clean and build your project and redeploy it in order to see if changes were applied.

Comment: i deleted the old class file and then recompiled. Even then I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around and not the correct procedure for invoking a servlet. Add the following line on to the top of your jsp page.

```
<%@page import="your-package-name.examples.servlet.ColorGetServlet"%>
```

like for example,

```
<%@page import="com.yourcompany.examples.servlet.ColorGetServlet"%>
```

this is not a good method because you're directly bypassing the web.xml fine and instead importing the servlet onto your jsp page. 
And in your page change `<input type=submit value="Submit">`
to

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

try the above and please comment if it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problem is in the action, please change it to

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="Form1" action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/ColorGetServlet" method="post">
<B>Color:</B>
<select name="color" size="1">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<br><br>
<input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the web.xml should look like this:

```
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ColorGetServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ColorGetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ColorGetServlet.ColorGetServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ColorGetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ColorGetServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I wish i was helpfull