# hide the data in the url using servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I want to hide the url data from the user by using servlet but i didnt get any solution.please anyone resolve this issue

Here  i am using three files.

First  i am calling servlet by using the java script  in the jsp file.Here is the javascript code:

reports_arb.jsp:

```
<html>
...
<script>
 ....
 ..

function generateReport(){
if(role=="dg")
{ 

    var depts=win.depts.value;

    var usercode=win.users.options[win.users.selectedIndex].value;

    if(usercode=="0")
    {

        return false;
    }

}
else if(role=="depthead")
{ 

    var usercode=win.users.options[win.users.selectedIndex].value;

    if(usercode=="0")
    {

        return false;
    }

}else if(role=="us"){

    var dg=win.dg.value;

    var depts=win.depts.value;

    var usercode=win.users.options[win.users.selectedIndex].value;

    if(usercode=="0")
    {

        return false;
    }


}
else
{alert("user");

    var usercode=win.logusers.value;
    alert(usercode);

}


    url="RedirectServlet?&FD="+FD+"&TD="+TD+"&actionid="+status+"&usercode="+usercode+"&action=reports"+"";
    window.open(url, '_blank',   'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=300,height=400,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');


    return true;
 }
 }
 </script>
....
...
...
..

 <button style="width: 135px; height: 25px;cursor:hand;" onClick="generatereport();">
.....

</html>
```

Second i am getting the values which are passed in the url into the servlet:

RedirectServlet.java

```
               //Getting values from Reports_arb.jsp

        String Fromdate=request.getParameter("FD");
        String Todate=request.getParameter("TD");
        String status=request.getParameter("actionid");
        String usercode=request.getParameter("usercode");

        //placing given values in a session 

        request.setAttribute("FD", Fromdate);
        request.setAttribute("TD", Todate);
        request.setAttribute("actionid", status);
        request.setAttribute("usercode", usercode);


        //Redirecting to showReport_arb.jsp
        //response.sendRedirect("showReport_arb.jsp");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("showReport_arb.jsp").forward(request,     response);
```

third thing is iam getting the above values into the jsp:

showReport_arb.jsp:

```
 String FD=request.getAttribute("FD").toString();
 String dtArray[]=FD.split("-");
 FD=dtArray[1]+"-"+dtArray[0]+"-"+dtArray[2];
  / /System.out.println("FD is---"+FD);
 String TD=request.getAttribute("TD").toString();
 String dtArray1[]=TD.split("-");
 TD=dtArray1[1]+"-"+dtArray1[0]+"-"+dtArray1[2];
//int actionto=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("actionto"));
 int actionid=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("actionid").toString());
  int usercode=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("usercode").toString());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `POST` in the form instead of `GET`

```
<form  method="post" ...>
```

and override `doPost()` in servlet class

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.I already tried with post but its not working fine.could you please suggest some more solutions

Comment: What you are getting exception if you use post

Comment: @PSR  HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL.iam calling servlet by using the javascript url then it directly calling the doGet method.if i write doPost() it gives above error.

Comment: @vaggaravi Have you implemented the `doPost()` inside your servlet?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie yes i implemented doPost only

Comment: @vaggaravi what is the problem you are facing

Comment: @vaggaravi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577414/http-status-405-http-method-post-is-not-supported-by-this-url I suggest you rebuild/redeploy your application OR you have not implemented the doPost...

Comment: in the above code,i have used doPost() and  redirecting the data(FD,TD,usercode....) to showreports_arb.jsp from the RedirectServlet but iam getting  HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Comment: i think you can set the method to post

Comment: @PSR just now i updated the above code please check it once and send me the answer